# What is a refresh token and how, where do you use it?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, azure-active-directory

I was creating an application to enable user to sign in with their Microsoft Account. But after the submission of email and password, it displays this error message "AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token". What is the problem? Here is the link to my GitHub project: https://github.com/JadyVella/OAuth2-with-MSAL

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the **AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed** Error code.

If your app reuses authorization codes to get tokens for multiple resources, its recommended that you use the code to get a refresh token, and then use that refresh token to acquire additional tokens for other resources. Authorization codes can only be used once, but refresh tokens can be used multiple times across multiple resources. Any new app that attempts to reuse an authentication code during the OAuth code flow will get an invalid_grant error.

For more information about refresh tokens, see [Refreshing the access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refreshing-the-access-tokens) . If using ADAL or MSAL, this is handled for you by the library - replace the second instance of `'AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync'` with `'AcquireTokenSilentAsync'`.

**Note :** If the issue is not resolved from above, Please reach out to Azure Support by clicking on (Help+Support) and creating a technical request to Azure as it may require assisted support.